# Samsung NP-100SP No sound from speakers

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, speakers

I have serious problem, I bought Samsung **NP-N100SP** notebook I installed windows 7 and all drivers.

But there is **no sound from the speakers**, when I put headphones I get sound. The driver (*Realtek High Definition Audio*) seem to be correctly installed, I reinstalled it many times, I even reinstalled windows.

I suspect that its related to mono/stereo sound, because in the website([NP-N100SP](http://www.samsung.com/ph/consumer/monitor-peripherals-printer/notebook-pc/netbook/NP-N100S-E02PH)) the speaker is 1.5 watts Mono Speaker (1.5 watts x 1) and in windows when its configured as stereo and i cant change it.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I tired with [VLC media player](http://get.videolan.org/vlc/2.0.6/win32/vlc-2.0.6-win32.exe) it has option to switch sound between Stereo and mono, but that doesn't help. May be its hardware problem.

Answer (score 1):

A few things you can do to check:

**When you play any sound via your speaker, does Windows recognize that there is a sound?**

To check this: Right click on the speaker icon (bottom right corner) and open "Volume Mixer" and then play some sound. If windows detects that sound do came out, you should see some movement (green bars going up and down, to match the sound).

If windows detects the sound, then some possibilities:

- Your speaker is broken OR
- There loose cable inside your laptop somewhere OR
- There is a misconfiguration in your windows OS (as what has happened before in my workplace)

For the first 2 items, I can't help, but for misconfiguration (wrong device set as default), you can check as below:

- Play something in the background (Music, video, youtube, etc)
- Right Click on the Speaker Icon (bottom right corner) and choose "Playback Devices"
- On the "Sound" Window that appears, you should see some "Speaker" or other devices there (as picture below). Note: You may have MORE devices than the sample below.
- If there are other devices, or other speakers, try right clicking on them, and choose "Test" to see if that device will make a sound. If it does, then it is your speaker. And you should right click on it again, and "Set as Default Device".
- If you tried to test all devices shown and still no sound, most likely you have hardware issue (either broken speaker, or loose cable).

  [image: Sound Window]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think its hardware, because other option doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Samsung NP-100SP No sound from speakers:

the solution I got for your audio troubles is to update the audio driver...
click the link for Samsung NP-N100SP Audio driver.

Please make sure that you use the update driver on device manager...

http://org.downloadcenter.samsung.com/downloadfile/ContentsFile.aspx?CDSite=UNI_PH&CttFileID=4948518&CDCttType=DR&ModelType=N&ModelName=NP-N100SP&VPath=DR/201202/20120227132846088/Sound_6.0.1.6499.ZIP

don't forget to follow if problem solve.
thank N enjoy. ^-^

Comment: You are giving a direct download link to a specific version 6.0.1.6499 of 'a' Samsung driver. [Please edit your answer](http://superuser.com/posts/842044/edit) so that it points to the page where the OP can get new drivers.